# Mod rewrite whit multipe variables

Tags: mod-rewrite

My .htaccess is in test and I have added the folowing commands.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^Categorie/([^.]+)$ test/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

If I check p in the index whit the url domain.com/test/Categorie/1 
I get demo1.

If I do domain.com/test/Categorie/1/somename/ 
I get a 404 error.

Everywhere on the internet I find this solution for my problem but stangly enough I can not get it working because I keep getting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^c([0-9]+).*\.html test/index.php?c=$1
```

is what I used to fix it.